# How to have additional field besides the fields in the model in ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model named Customer and modelForm named Customer, but in my form i need more fields than the fields in Model. For example i want a confPass field in my ModelForm.
Code for Model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(unique=True, validators=[validate_mobile], max_length=10)
    state = models.CharField(choices=STATES, max_length=2)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'mobile_no', 'state', 'city', 'password']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Enter Name', 'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Enter Email', 'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['mobile_no'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Enter Mobile Number   ', 'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['state'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['city'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Enter City', 'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the field to your `CustomerForm` class and include it in `fields` list:

```
class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    confPass = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'mobile_no', 'state', 'city', 'password', 'confPass']
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this for a GenericRelation field, 'task'.  I wanted to add a field that was in the model but wouldn't display in the ModelForm.  I was able to update the field only using the shell.  I added an  tag after the form and then processed the response in the def form_valid() function.  My problem was that I have a task_app that I use for different models, so I needed a GenericRelation.

views.py

```
class ProjectModelUpdateView(UpdateView):
model = ProjectModel
# fields = '__all__'
form_class = ProjectModelForm
success_url = '/projects_app/'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.updated_by = self.request.user
    project = ProjectModel.objects.get(id=form.instance.id)
    project.task.create(created_by=self.request.user, task=self.request.POST['task'])
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

HTML

```
    <form method="post">

        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            <label class="control-label" for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5 border rounded form-outline">
                {{ field }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <label class="control-label" for="id_task">Task</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5 border rounded form-outline">
            <input type="text" name="task" maxlength="64" class="form-control" id="id_task">
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
```